# Save multiple pie charts created using Highcharts as an image and export it into Excel?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, phpexcel

I have multiple pie charts that's created using **highcharts.js**. I have already built an Excel export to export the table from the HMTL page to Excel. Now, I would like to export the pie charts So, that when the user clicks the "Export to Excel" button everything is in the excel file. Is this even possible? If not could I save the charts as images and insert them into the export as well as the other information?

**What I have tried:**

I spend a lot of time searching on solution but i don't have any idea how can i do it

**Update**

**My PHP Script:**

```
/*
//some code to get the date from database and encode it to json
*/
if(isset($_GET["getuser1"])){
    echo json_encode($getuser1);
    die;

}
```

**My javascript :**

```
 $.ajax({
            url:'userreport.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                "getuser1":"",
                "from":date},
            success:function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
             var user1=[];


             var count=0;

             for(key in data){
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                     user1.push({"name":key,"y":data[key]});

                     count++;

                    }
                }

            // console.log(user1);
    //////////////////////////////

    Highcharts.chart('user1', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: true,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'user1'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}  (  <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%  )',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data:user1

                }]
    }); 
                }

            });
```

Comment: Can you provide more informations ? How do you generate the image ? Do you use the built in export capabilities of highcharts ? Also give some bits of code my help as well.

Comment: I update my questions

Comment: Highcharts provides export module (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview) which lets you to export charts into PDF, PNG, JPG or SVG format. You just need to find the way to store that image in the excel file. You could also create a chart inside excel, based on series data (http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/). If you are using PHPExcel, this site should be helpful: https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/.

Comment: yes exactly ,now the only way is to store the chart as image and insert it into excel file , But I do not think this thing was done before ,so it is the same problem, HOW it possible?